# Filling a database with color values

Tags: php, mysql, html, apache, xampp

We are using Xampp for simulating an apache and mysql server.
I don't know exactly what the problem is. When I check the database, there's no value in it.

database:http://de.tinypic.com/r/53285/8

This my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="data.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="Color" value="b" id="r"/>
<label for="radio">ROT</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="Color" value="b" id="g"/>
<label for="radio">GR&Uuml;N</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="Color" value="b" id="b"/>
<label for="radio">BLAU</label></br>
<button type="submit">Absenden</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

This is my php code:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lightcontrol");
if(!$db)
{
exit("Verbindungsfehler: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST["Color"]))
{

if($_POST["Color"]=="r")
{
$variable =" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(`1`,,`255`,`0`,`0`)";
}
if($_POST["Color"]=="g")
{
$variable =" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(`1`,,`0`,`255`,`0`)";
}
if($_POST["Color"]=="b")
{
$variable =" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(`1`,,`0`,`0`,`255`)";
}
}
var_dump($variable);
mysqli_query($db,$variable);

?>
```

Comment: I think your query is completely wrong. Can you show us what your database tables look like?

Comment: http://de.tinypic.com/r/53285/8

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by others, your query is wrong.
[Check documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) to see how `INSERT` must be done

Also, you use `mysqli` and `mysql` in same code.
If you start to connect to your database with [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php), you have to do your queries with it.

```
mysqli_query($db, $variable);
```

Comment: still error:

if(isset($_POST["Color"])) { if($_POST["Color"]=="r") { $variable .=" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(1,,255,0,0);"; } if($_POST["Color"]=="g") { $variable .=" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(1,,0,255,0);"; } if($_POST["Color"]=="b") { $variable .=" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(1,,0,0,255);";//Line 23 } } mysql_query($variable); ?> Undefined variable: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\data.php on line 23

Comment: OK, fixed the error.
Now, the problem is that there are no values in my database.

Comment: Did it 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @LukasBlauensteiner Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.error.php) to see error (and it's probably because you have 2 dash following)

Answer (score 1):

Because your query is wrong.

You are adding a new row in the table 255?

This is the correct statement for adding a new row

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Comment: Remember that `value1` is mostly the `ID`, which is autoincremented.

Comment: if(isset($_POST["Color"]))
    {

    if($_POST["Color"]=="r")
    {
    $variable .=" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(`1`,,`255`,`0`,`0`);";
    }
    if($_POST["Color"]=="g")
    {
    $variable .=" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(`1`,,`0`,`255`,`0`);";
    }
    if($_POST["Color"]=="b")
    {
    $variable .=" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(`1`,,`0`,`0`,`255`);";//Line 26 
    }

    }

    mysql_query($variable);

    ?>

Undefined variable: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\data.php on line 26

Comment: What is your line 26? Do a `var_dump($variable)` just before the query statement, is not defined so you have a problem in your post. That is the first error. Then, as someone else said, you have to user `mysqli_query()`. Then, your query is wrong. `INSERT INTO table VALUES (value)`, I don't see the table `valuetb` in your picture...

Comment: Because the whole table is "valuetb"

Answer (score 0):

Add ";" end of each variable

instead of

```
$variable =" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(`1`,,`255`,`0`,`0`)";
```

Use:

```
$variable =" INSERT INTO valuetb VALUES(`1`,,`255`,`0`,`0`);";
```

Comment: thanks, but there are still no values in my database.